# Smart Data Self-Test Failed

Tags: disk, disk-utility, smart

When I run the Smart Data Self-Test disk utility the result indicates Smart Self Test Failed.  Yet when I look at the individual test, they all say OK.  Did the test itself fail or did the disk fail the test?  Running version 12.10 .....

Answer (score 2):

Certain SMART details could have been triggered in the past, this would cause it to pass or fail, but still report everything is fine now. If this is a multi-disk system, pull it and run the manufacturers scripts.

If this is a single disk, continue to test, it is likely an intermittent failure that will appear in full soon enough